# tree privileges database design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm unsure into how to ask this so i will try to illustrate with an example.

What i am trying to achieve is an application that will be able to discern different levels of privileges. and i can't figure out how my database and queries should be made.

there are this levels of user:

1. Director
2. Manager
3. Executive

So a column in my user table will be a privilege INT to know what type of user, and another column will be Parent user, since x amount of Executives will be assigned to a manager, and x amount of managers will be assigned to a Director.

Example table USERS:

```
ID    username    privilege   parent
1     Director1   1           null
2     Director2   1           null
3     Manager1    2           1
4     Manager2    2           1
5     Manager3    2           2
6     Executive1  3           3
7     Executive2  3           3
8     Executive3  3           4
9     Executive4  3           4
10    Executive5  3           5
11    Executive6  3           5
```

And they will have their "costumers".

Example table COSTUMERS

```
ID  name  seller
1   c1    11
2   c2    10
3   c3    10
4   c4    9
5   c5    8
6   c6    7
7   c7    6
8   c8    5
9   c9    4
10  c10   3 
11  c11   2
12  c12   1
```

so if an Executive went into the app it would only be able to see their own costumers.

but if a manager went in he would be able to see his costumers and also from the executives assigned to him. and the same happens to the directors.

Is this the right way to make it? if so what would be the best approach to an effective query?

example diagram( you can see the organization diagram and each of the costmer every user has.[image: diagram]

for example if users was to check his costumers he should see:

Director1:  C12,C10,C9,C7,C6,C5,C4

Director2:  C11,C8,C3,C2,C1

Manager1:   C10,C7,C6

Manager2:   C9,C5,C4

Manager3: C8,C3,C2,C1

and the executives only would see their own costumers.

Comment: Your given sample from above doesn't have any relation to each table.

Comment: Seller is the user id

Comment: try to complete it.

Comment: where is c1 c2 etc came from?

Comment: @reds its just names costumer1 costumer2 etc

Comment: what do you mean by this `x amount of Executives will be assigned to a manager, and x amount of managers will be assigned to a Director.`?

Comment: it means like the example, a manager might have x number of executives below him, like manager1 has executive1 and executive2 under him.

Comment: Kindly provide an expected result.

Comment: @reds i updated the post with some info, i hope that clarifies my point

Comment: As iv'e told you your problem here is `Your given sample from above doesn't have any relation to each table.`

Comment: @reds mmm, yes, the seller column is the id from the user.

Comment: Hierarchies are difficult to do in SQL.  Think about ways to flatten things.  Such as with "roles" that represent persons and a different set of "roles" for what customers are visible.  Then build a matrix of "this person-role can see that customer-role.  Sounds like it might be only 3x3 matrix -- a 9-row table that is hand built with constants.